# In a world where everyone has a tracking implant, how might those be subverted?

Tags: technology, dystopia

In a dystopian world where all citizens are tracked through a small device under their skin, how might one go about "outsmarting" the technology to move about unimpeded? My only thought is that some might physically cut it out and carry it around, leaving it behind when desiring to move about.

Comment: Why doesn't an ordinary cooking aluminium foil wrapped around the arm work?

Comment: @AlexP

Looks like it might!
https://www.instamotoring.com/does-aluminum-foil-block-gps-tracking/

Still, eliminating the signal all together might raise red flags.

Comment: The human body has several pockets that could serve.  Some bodies are more pockety than others.    @AlexP I imagine that if Big Brother lost the signal that would prompt someone to come check the last known location of the tracked individual.

Comment: I think for a good answer you need to more narrowly define the device. Does it get GPS and send that out? Is it encrypted? Does the hero know that encryption? Or does it just send "a signal" (such as an ID number) and the location is derived by the receivers (kinda like a cellphone -- towers don't know your GPS location, they just know you're in the area of the tower). I have some ideas but it gets wordy if I have to also guess about the capabilities of the device itself. You could possibly ask another question if you need ideas about how the device should function.

Comment: @JamieB I haven't given it much thought. As far as the story goes, it functions to indicate when the individual is in their residence and when they are at work- so it could be rather crude.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might edit that update into your question for others. Not everyone reads the comments! I think it makes the question a lot clearer. (That the tracker "could be rather crude", so at least we know we aren't designing against encrypted GPS transmitters.)

Comment: @AlexP , that would certainly foil their attempts to track you

Comment: You really need to specify the device better to have a significant answer. At the very least I would expect the device to emit its ID, timestamp, encrypted string. The encrypted string would change at every 'ping' and have to match with a pattern recorded in the security systems. So that the signal could not be faked.  Try to imagine what the device does and what does not.

Comment: "It functions to indicate when the individual is in their residence and when they are at work".  It's not much of a dystopian world if that's all the tracker is used for...

Comment: As a rule of thumb making an already broad question broader isn't a good way to get it reopened.

Comment: @sphennings Perhaps, I misunderstood. But I thought it was closed because it was too specific. "Too story based"- so I tried to remove any specific plot elements.

Comment: @MattBenjamin You did make the question less story based but that lead to you also making the question too broad. As written you're asking us to brainstorm and generate ideas something that is prohibited on this site.

Comment: @sphennings I see. My mistake.

Answer (score 14):

You mentioned (in a comment) that the device itself "may be rather crude", so I'm going to suggest the device is a fairly straightforward transmitter that simply says something like "ID 2568729" and local receivers detect this and know roughly where you are (likely within a relatively narrow area, say, 50 meters -- weak transmitter but a pretty fine net of receivers).

Given that constraint, it should be fairly simple: when the protagonist needs a night out on the town, he covers his transmitter. Search for "faraday fabric". I have actually tried one of these and it does work, at least for common frequencies that a transmitter like this would likely use. The transmitter is in his arm, he wears a faraday fabric wrap there and the signal can't be detected. As he does this, he activates his device, which is simply a recording of his own transmitter, set on a loop. Possibly he makes this switch while in the shower. Water tends to interfere with signals (also how your microwave oven works -- the interference manifests as heat within water) and I think it's at least plausible that a weak transmitter would be even weaker in a shower (or bath), so any "blip" of his making the switch should be easy to write off, given a primitive system to begin with.

The important thing is that he appears to be at home while any nefarious deeds go down, and his wrap-and-repeater plan should be good enough.

As for the flesh pocket, "go for it". I have no idea how realistic it is but it seems plausible and it's not uncommon in sleuth stories. [GURPS](https://gurps4e.fandom.com/wiki/Flesh_Pocket) even has a rule for it. I imagine a real one would be like any piercing: use it or lose it, because the body keeps trying to close it up, but it is otherwise a healed up pocket. But the faraday fabric makes it fairly unnecessary. Getting caught with the fabric is probably a lot like being caught with your transmitter in a flesh pocket, so the solution is probably a personal preference for you.

Comment: The implant could very easily be a passive RFID chip that has no power source of its own and uses the power from signals emitted by an active scanner to send its response. This is how modern foot races like 5ks and marathons track participants timing.  

The circuit is usually pretty simple, so it might emit a static id code that could be copied and re-broadcast like your suggestion.  

A more advanced circuit would use rolling codes like your garage door opener and would be a lot harder to duplicate undetected.

Comment: @abestrange Yeah, RFID chip would be simplest, but I think implies more of a "checkpoint" system -- they put readers in all the doorways. You can bypass the system by just knowing which doorways to avoid. An implanted transmitter requires, I think, a sci-fi power source but would give the dystopian government a better ability to see locations at all times, even if they just sit in their house.

Answer (score 6):

- Bribe a clerk in the surveillance office. Of course the clerk might not stay bought.
- Carry some sort of jammer in the pocket. Either the jammer sends white noise on the relevant frequencies, or it sends a false signal with higher power than the genuine signal. Being pocket-sized and not implanted, the jammer will have a bigger antenna and battery than the tracking beacon, which should help. This would be a black market item, and last year's gizmo might no longer work against this year's receivers.
- Cause a failure of selected tracking receivers, through 'ordinary' valdalism or 'routine' wear and tear. Kind of difficult when everybody is tracked.

Comment: If the jammer is more powerful than the real device, what would prevent it from also jamming anyone else who came near you?  I think if the tracking people noticed a travelling blackout zone, they might send someone to investigate that...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, that would have to be calibrated. Think of it as a traveling glitch, not a blackout zone.

Answer (score 6):

I don't want to dig out the miniature device embedded in my arm - that sounds painful, risky and may leave a scar.

Instead, I am going to forge 200 more of them - all transmitting my id, and hide them in the belongings of other people.

The authorities won't know which one is me.

Wait, but they will know *I* am up to no good, even if they don't know where I was.

So, I am going to make 40,000 more, sharing the ids of 200 random people. I may need a bit of a conspiracy to spread these around, but with a few volunteers to help (perhaps in return for having their id used in the mix), the authorities won't know which of us were up to what shenanigans, and which were innocent bystanders.

Comment: The only problem is the purchasing of the raw devices. If you were employed by a company that needed similar devices for inventory control, then diverting some to personal use might be possible without raising suspicion.

Comment: the device doesn't need to be the same, just to behave the same

Comment: @DavidR: I am assuming it can be constructed from off-the-shelf electronics parts. The specs would be much less onerous than the implants - it could be larger, have shorter battery life, higher failure rates, etc.

Comment: Making 40,000 biomedical transceivers without the authorities noticing, and getting 40,000 people to replace their existing trackers with *your* trackers is -- without a doubt -- doomed to failure.

Comment: Ah, the good ol' Spartacus defense.

Comment: @RonJohn: I think there is a misunderstanding. I am not making 40,000 *biomedical* transceivers. I am making 40,000 regular transceivers. I am not *replacing* their existing trackers in their arms. I am adding trackers to their purses, backpacks, laptop bags, clothes, cars, pet collars, parcels, etc. If 20% get discovered, that's okay. Depending on their attitude to authorities, they may volunteer to carry them.

Comment: Ok, but still doomed to failure, since it requires 40,000 people to cooperate/ not squeal on you.

Comment: @RonJohn: I don't understand where you are getting that from. 40,000 is a lot, and requires a conspiracy (perhaps at the organised crime level) but not everyone needs to cooperate, and if some of them discover the devices and report them to the authorities it doesn't hurt much.

Comment: @Oddthinking My point is that diverting 40,000 off the shelf parts from legitimate use to your use can be noticed quite easily. Even gray market or black-market sources will have trouble providing that many parts. And if you need any assembly or to process the programming of that many parts, you will need to have a factory. Someone will notice if just the local zoning board.

Comment: @DavidR: I agree with your points. But I also take inspiration that, in our world, Swiss watch manufacturers estimate 40 million *fake* watches are produced a year. Perhaps the tracking devices can be similarly smuggled in from another country which doesn't respect the laws? I don't know if that breaks the OP's world or not.

Answer (score 5):

Technology, as everyone knows, is *awful*.

The range of a tracking *implant* is limited. It doesn't have any space for a decent power supply or antenna, and given its size and location it can't be expected to transmit far and so will be challenging to read from a distance. They won't be speaking to distant infrastructure like mobile phone masts or satellites, and they won't be doing complex things like recording your movements for later upload. You need something mobile-phone sized to do that kind of tracking, and whilst you *can* put mobile-phone-sized objects in various parts of people it gets a bit uncomfortable a bit fast, and there are issues of charging and signal attenuation and so on. Very short range implantable [RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rfid_tag) [microchips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchip_implant_(human)) are probably the things you'll be working with... not really *tracking implants* but merely ID chips that computer networks will use to do tracking... an important distinction.

This means in order to track people effectively, you need a huge number of scanning devices. In practise you might only fit them at "choke points"... entrances to shops or places of work or vehicles and public transport and so on. In a busy city, those scanners require an even shorter range, because deciphering multiple overlapping return pings becomes increasing impractical. In less urban terrain sensors might be quite widely separated, so going "off grid" is one option, though it comes at the expense of being limited in your ability to do stuff

You can therefore avoid being tracked in public if you a) avoid places with scanners, so your implant doesn't get triggered, or b) you remove or shield the tracking implant and make sure to only visit crowded places which don't have turnstiles (big shops, fine, public transport, probably not fine) giving you plausible deniability that your implant didn't ping.

There's simply too much data out there to be able to audit every person and every ID ping, and the collection processes will be unreliable. All you have to do, then, is avoid your trail of ID pings looking "suspicious". Your friend (or an unsuspecting plant) can carry around a pocketful of ID tags, and so long as the tags are never associated with any crimes the chances of anyone auditing security camera footage and discovering that the clump of really intimate people who hang around together all the time is slim. Audits are expensive and time consuming, and there are literally billions of boring people out there doing boring things boringly. No-one can check up on all of them.

Just make sure that your ID is associated with regular comings and goings at your house and at the shops and you should be beneath suspicion. You don't have to be at home or shopping, but instead doing whatever nefarious thing you don't want the authorities to know about. Work is trickier, as people might notice if you're not doing your job, so you probably need to be there in person, but maybe you should get a better job?

> would it be to create a "pocket" of healed flesh to store the tracker when it's supposed to be on his/her person?

If I were an evil dystopian enforcer, looking for unusual scars or healing marks around the site of the implant would be high up on my list of of things to do with dissidents.

Tampering with implants is likely to be a serious crime. If I'm suspicious of you (and of course I would be), and I'm suitably immoral (probably a requirement of my job), I can take a pocket knife to your implant location. Not to dig it all the way out, but just to make a bit of a mess. Boom, next time you get stopped and checked the next enforcer will see the scars and you can be arrested and jailed. Not a very clever means of framing people, but quite expedient.

Answer (score 2):

There are already good answers, so I will try to approach your question in different (and likely, less helpful) manner.

Let's take a closer look at this situation.

"In a dystopian world where all **citizens** are tracked through a small device in their arm"

This is the key word. We need to figure out how to stop being a citizen. I see two ways.

1.Renounce your citizenship. You stop being a citizen, thus you are not required to carry said tracking implant anymore.

2.Fake your own death. Dead people aren't citizens, thus the System stops wondering "where is citizen X?", as from its point of view said citizen just stopped existing, rendering tracking meaningless. You're not a part of the System anymore.

Comment: Being a respectable citizen is however *very* advantageous, especially where the rule of law is not upheld.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to counter a device, get into the mind of the device builder...

Suppose you want to track where people are. You could have each device respond to a central service. This might mean we have dead areas. Or the devices might report which other devices they are close to, like Bluetooth devices. This may mean you can cross-check the location from other devices. This might be helpful if you want to track a lot of people crowded on a train going through a tunnel, where reception is poor. If no-one gets off the train, the devices have little to report, and the bandwidth can be used effectively.

The devices might also detect what you are doing, from your heartbeat, from your acceleration, from any geolocation signals, and by communicating with nearby devices, and from the occasional direct checks from authority. The sudden disappearance of a device should trigger alarms from neighbours.

So, how would you counter this? You might somehow screen your device from any incoming signals, and use some broadband 2-way transmission, so you relay all the signals from your device at point A to point B, and return all the signals from point B to point A. This way your device and all the devices at point B would be convinced you had actually been there. You would have to be fairly close to pull this off but it might work.

A more risky approach might be to use AI to simulate signals from point B to your device at point A, and a second device to simulate signals at point B as though they were from your device. You would be found out if anyone checked your device history against the people you were supposed to have passed. But, if you are one ordinary person in a crowd, why would they?

Answer (score 1):

**Tracker will be in service animal.**

It could have been a service dog but I actually have a service wombat.  I put my tracker in the wombat.  It was ok with that.  The tracker usually corresponds with my general location because Woms goes almost everywhere with me, providing service as it does.

There is a bar ("The Less Dystopian") I sometimes go to by myself because Woms harbors a grudge against one of the waitresses there.  When I am at the bar it looks to those tracking me like I am still home, and actually home in bed because if I am not there to shake the can full of pebbles the bed is where Woms goes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's say this is a weird planet (not ours of course!) where devices can find where they are by receiving radio signals off of a network of satellites with atomic clocks in geo-synchronous orbit. How such a network might work is explained in more detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Principles). We'll call this the "Planetary Positioning System" (PPS).

However, on this weird planet they also have aircraft travel. That can be somewhat dangerous, so training the pilots is important. To help create these trainers, it's nice to use the same equipment that's on the real aircraft as much as possible, including their PPS systems. This is just one example, as anyone testing any device at all that contains a PPS system may have this issue.

So anyway what people making these trainers do is buy devices that can be programmed to send the same signals as the PPS satellites in a way that the tracker they are placed near will calculate to be at a location of your choice. Created correctly, they will produce the strongest signal to the nearby device, but not strong enough to mess with any other further away device.

So the trick here in this weird world would be getting one of these devices redirected from engineering tasks to personal use.

Comment: Do aircraft simulators *actually* **broadcast** *real* GPS signals, or do they simulate the signals inside the simulator.  (I'm guessing it's an internal simulation.)

Comment: And, of course, the protagonist would have to know what signal is generated by his arm tracker (encryption method, the key, etc).  And any dystopian government worth it's salt will highly regulate those external generators.  Moreover, they'll have thought about people trying to remove and spoof them, so will add safeguards like temperature checking, pulse, maybe regular DNA tests, etc.

Comment: @RonJohn - Not really. If the tracker thinks he's sitting at home (because that's what the incoming PPS signals are telling it), you don't care that its still reporting the results. Yes, the generators are regulated, which is why I said in the last sentence that getting your hands on one would be the real trick. I'd guess bribery, swiping one from a supposedly destroyed device, or ... HEIST TIME!